# Market capitalization of BSE 100

Tags: india, market-indexes

What fraction of the monetary value of stocks is represented by BSE 100? (For comparison, I remember reading that NIFTY 100 represents market cap of 77%)

I tried searching online, but could not easily find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in the factsheet available at https://us.spindices.com/indices/equity/sp-bse-100  - 2/3.